# JavaPoet - Exception unexpected

Tags: java, exception, enumset, javapoet

So, I'm making a program that takes a Class Diagram and, using JavaPoet, converts it in Java code.

The class Diagram is not written in UML, it's already modelled inside the program with java.

Here is the code portion giving me problems:
(parsing all the attributes inside a class, to add them to the new source code, and to add Setters/Getters if missing)

```
for (Attribute a : classe.attributes) { //Parse all the attribute inside the class

    TypeName aClass = stringToType(a.getType()); //the attribute tipe

    FieldSpec aField = FieldSpec.builder(aClass, a.getName()) //the attribute
            .addModifiers(javax.lang.model.element.Modifier.valueOf(a.getProtection().toUpperCase()), a.isStatic() ? Modifier.STATIC : null)
            .build();
    fields.add(aField);

    MethodSpec aMethod = MethodSpec.methodBuilder("set" + upperFirst(a.getName()))
            .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC, a.isStatic() ? Modifier.STATIC : null)
            .returns(TypeName.VOID)
            .addParameter(aClass, a.getName())
            .addStatement("this." + a.getName() + " = " + a.getName())
            .build();
    if (!methods.contains(aMethod)) //if not present, add the set method
        methods.add(aMethod);


    MethodSpec bMethod = MethodSpec.methodBuilder("get" + upperFirst(a.getName()))
            .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC, a.isStatic() ? Modifier.STATIC : null)
            .addStatement("return " + a.getName())
            .returns(aClass)
            .build();

    if (!methods.contains(bMethod)) methods.add(bMethod); //if not present, add the get method


}
```

I get the following exception right on the last line:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.EnumSet.typeCheck(EnumSet.java:396)
    at java.util.RegularEnumSet.add(RegularEnumSet.java:161)
    at java.util.RegularEnumSet.add(RegularEnumSet.java:36)
    at java.util.EnumSet.copyOf(EnumSet.java:179)
    at com.squareup.javapoet.CodeWriter.emitModifiers(CodeWriter.java:172)
    at com.squareup.javapoet.MethodSpec.emit(MethodSpec.java:86)
    at com.squareup.javapoet.MethodSpec.toString(MethodSpec.java:164)
    at com.squareup.javapoet.MethodSpec.equals(MethodSpec.java:153)
    at java.util.ArrayList.indexOf(ArrayList.java:317)
    at java.util.ArrayList.contains(ArrayList.java:300)
```

HERE IS THE CODE I POSTED ->

```
    at base.controller.commands.ExportModelCommand.execute(ExportModelCommand.java:224)
    at base.Main.executeCommand(Main.java:113)
    at base.controller.menu.menuitem.ItemExport.lambda$new$0(ItemExport.java:17)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(MenuItem.java:462)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1405)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.lambda$createChildren$343(ContextMenuContent.java:1358)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:380)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:294)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:415)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And I really cannot understand why.

I tried to debug, I couldn't find anything at NULL. How do I find the problem?

WHOLE CODE - CLASS MODEL (the omitted part is getters/setters)

```
public class ClassModel {

    private String name = "";
    private String parent = null;
    public ArrayList<Attribute> attributes = new ArrayList<Attribute>();
    public ArrayList<Method> methods = new ArrayList<Method>();
    public boolean isInterface;
    private boolean isFinal;
    private ProtectionLevel prote;
    private String genericText="";
    private String stereotype="";

    public ClassModel() {
        }

    public ClassModel(ClassModel original) {
        this.name = original.name;
        this.parent = original.parent;
        this.isInterface = original.isInterface;

        /*
        for (Map.Entry<String, Relation> e : original.relations.entrySet()) {
            this.relations.put(e.getKey(), new Relation(e.getValue()));
        }
        */
        for (Attribute a : original.attributes) {
            this.attributes.add(new Attribute(a));
        }
        for (Method m : original.methods) {
            this.methods.add(new Method(m));
        }
    }
```

WHOLE CODE - EXPORT COMMAND :

```
public Message execute() {
    ///////////////////
        /*    Save As    */
    ///////////////////


    // Set tab flag to saved and remove '*' from tab name

    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("./"));
    chooser.setDialogTitle("Choose your folder");
    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);


    if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        for (Tab tab : Main.project.getTabContainer().getTabs()) {
            BaseDiagramModel currentModel = ((UMLTab) tab).getModel();
            if (currentModel.getDiagramPosition() == 2) {


                for (UMLElement e : currentModel) {
                    if (e instanceof UMLClassElementImage) {
                        //prepare content for new file java


                        ClassModel classe = ((UMLClassElementImage) e).modelClass;


                        ArrayList<MethodSpec> methods = new ArrayList<MethodSpec>();
                        ArrayList<FieldSpec> fields = new ArrayList<FieldSpec>();
                        ArrayList<UMLElement> composition = new ArrayList<UMLElement>();
                        ArrayList<UMLElement> aggregation = new ArrayList<UMLElement>();
                        ArrayList<UMLElement> inheritance = new ArrayList<UMLElement>();
                        for (UMLElement x : ((UMLNode<UMLElement>) e).getChildren()) {
                            if (x instanceof UMLArrowAggregation) {
                                aggregation.add(x);

                            } else if (x instanceof UMLArrowComposition) {
                                composition.add(x);

                            } else if (x instanceof UMLArrowEreditarieta) {
                                inheritance.add(x);

                            }
                            //else if (x instanceof UMLArrowDashedLineWithCentralLabelAndApexOnHead) {
                             //   implementation.add(x);
                            //}
                        }

                        for (UMLElement aggregated : aggregation) {
                            UMLElement whatIsAfterTheArrow = ((UMLNode<UMLElement>) aggregated).getChildren().get(0);
                            ClassModel classeAgg = ((UMLClassElementImage) whatIsAfterTheArrow).modelClass;

                            FieldSpec aField = FieldSpec.builder(ClassName.get("", classeAgg.getName()), classeAgg.getName())
                                    .addModifiers(Modifier.PROTECTED)
                                    .build();
                            fields.add(aField);

                            MethodSpec aMethod = MethodSpec.methodBuilder("set" + upperFirst(classeAgg.getName()))
                                    .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC)
                                    .returns(TypeName.VOID)
                                    .addParameter(ClassName.get("", classeAgg.getName()), classeAgg.getName())
                                    .addStatement("this." + classeAgg.getName() + " = " + classeAgg.getName())
                                    .build();
                            if (!methods.contains(aMethod)) methods.add(aMethod);
                            MethodSpec bMethod = MethodSpec.methodBuilder("get" + upperFirst(classeAgg.getName()))
                                    .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC)
                                    .addStatement("return " + classeAgg.getName())
                                    .returns(ClassName.get("", classeAgg.getName()))
                                    .build();
                            if (!methods.contains(bMethod)) methods.add(bMethod);

                        }

                        for (UMLElement composed : composition) {
                            UMLElement whatIsAfterTheArrow = ((UMLNode<UMLElement>) composed).getChildren().get(0);
                            ClassModel classeComp = ((UMLClassElementImage) whatIsAfterTheArrow).modelClass;

                            FieldSpec aField = FieldSpec.builder(ClassName.get("", classeComp.getName()), classeComp.getName())
                                    .addModifiers(Modifier.PROTECTED, Modifier.FINAL)
                                    .build();
                            fields.add(aField);

                            MethodSpec aMethod = MethodSpec.methodBuilder("set" + upperFirst(classeComp.getName()))
                                    .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC)
                                    .returns(TypeName.VOID)
                                    .addParameter(ClassName.get("", classeComp.getName()), classeComp.getName())
                                    .addStatement("this." + classeComp.getName() + " = " + classeComp.getName())
                                    .build();
                            if (!methods.contains(aMethod)) methods.add(aMethod);
                            MethodSpec bMethod = MethodSpec.methodBuilder("get" + upperFirst(classeComp.getName()))
                                    .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC)
                                    .addStatement("return " + classeComp.getName())
                                    .returns(ClassName.get("", classeComp.getName()))
                                    .build();
                            if (!methods.contains(bMethod)) methods.add(bMethod);

                        }

                        for (Attribute a : classe.attributes) {

                            TypeName aClass = stringToType(a.getType());

                            FieldSpec aField = FieldSpec.builder(aClass, a.getName())
                                    .addModifiers(javax.lang.model.element.Modifier.valueOf(a.getProtection().toUpperCase()), a.isStatic() ? Modifier.STATIC : null)
                                    .build();
                            fields.add(aField);

                            MethodSpec aMethod = MethodSpec.methodBuilder("set" + upperFirst(a.getName()))
                                    .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC, a.isStatic() ? Modifier.STATIC : null)
                                    .returns(TypeName.VOID)
                                    .addParameter(aClass, a.getName())
                                    .addStatement("this." + a.getName() + " = " + a.getName())
                                    .build();
                            if (!methods.contains(aMethod))
                                methods.add(aMethod);


                            MethodSpec bMethod = MethodSpec.methodBuilder("get" + upperFirst(a.getName()))
                                    .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC, a.isStatic() ? Modifier.STATIC : null)
                                    .addStatement("return " + a.getName())
                                    .returns(aClass)
                                    .build();

                            if (!methods.contains(bMethod)) methods.add(bMethod);


                        }

                        for (Method m : classe.methods) {


                            ArrayList<ParameterSpec> parametriSpec = new ArrayList<>();
                            Set<Attribute> parametri = m.getParameters();

                            for (Attribute singleParam : parametri) {
                                TypeName attClass = stringToType(singleParam.getType());


                                ParameterSpec test = ParameterSpec.builder(attClass, singleParam.getName())
                                        // .addModifiers(Modifier.FINAL)
                                        .build();
                                parametriSpec.add(test);
                            }

                            TypeName aClass = stringToType(m.getReturnType());

                            MethodSpec aMethod = MethodSpec.methodBuilder(m.getName())

                                    .addModifiers(javax.lang.model.element.Modifier.valueOf(m.getProtection().toUpperCase()), m.isStatic() ? Modifier.STATIC : null)
                                    .returns(aClass)
                                    .addParameters(parametriSpec)
                                    .build();

                            methods.add(aMethod);
                        }
                        TypeSpec theClass = null;


                        TypeName father = null;
                        if (!inheritance.isEmpty())
                            father = ClassName.get("", ((UMLClassElementImage) ((UMLNode<UMLElement>) inheritance.get(0)).getChildren().get(0)).modelClass.getName());
                        try {



                            theClass = TypeSpec.classBuilder(classe.getName())
                                    .addModifiers(((UMLClassElementImage) e).modelClass.getFinal() ? new Modifier[] { javax.lang.model.element.Modifier.valueOf(classe.getProte().toString().toUpperCase()), Modifier.FINAL} : new Modifier[] { javax.lang.model.element.Modifier.valueOf(classe.getProte().toString().toUpperCase()) })
                                    .addModifiers(javax.lang.model.element.Modifier.valueOf(classe.getProte().toString().toUpperCase()), Modifier.FINAL)
                                    .superclass(father == null ? ClassName.OBJECT : father)
                                    .addMethods(methods)
                                    .addFields(fields)
                                    .build();



                            // Create object to choose and create new file


                        } catch (Exception exc) {

                            getFailureMessage("Il nome della classe potrebbe essere sbagliato?");

                        }


                        try {
                            JavaFile javaFile = JavaFile.builder(currentModel.getTitle(), theClass)
                                    .build();
                            Path javaPath = Paths.get(chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath());
                            javaFile.writeTo(javaPath);

                        } catch (Exception exc) {
                            exc.printStackTrace();
                            return getFailureMessage();

                        }


                    }
                    //Else is not a class
                }


            }


        }
    else if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION)
        return getFailureMessage("Esportazione annullata");


    // Save jsonArray into a file
    // JsonFileManager jsonFileManager = new JsonFileManager();
    // jsonFileManager.save(jsonArray, Main.project.getName() + ".citro");

    return getSuccessMessage();

}
```

Comment: Can you share your code please ?

Comment: I added the command Code and the Class Model Code (i omtitted setters/getters) 

But I don't think that would bring you anywhere :(

Comment: As a guess , would you like to print/check for null all your created MethodSpec objects before calling the contains method on ArrayList containing MethodSpec objects.

Comment: But... the exception happens here: ||| 

if (!methods.contains(bMethod)) methods.add(bMethod); //if not present, add the get method 
|||

and a moment before there is this:
|||
 if (!methods.contains(aMethod)) //if not present, add the set method
                                methods.add(aMethod);

Which does not throw exceptions

Comment: Looks like something internal in JavaPoet is getting `null` when it expects a modifier like `PUBLIC`. It should fail earlier and it's not.

Comment: How can you know that it's about the modifiers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem were the lines like this one:

```
.addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC, a.isStatic() ? Modifier.STATIC : null)
```

I discovered it later, but addModifiers(null), instead of doing nothing, makes the whole thing explode

Comment: This should probably be reported as an issue on https://github.com/square/javapoet , either filtering before calling `EnumSet.copyOf` or preventing `null` from being a valid value.